# Assigning values to const in javascript right-left vs left-right

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants, variable-assignment, destructuring

I was looking at a react code base where I saw this type of code snippet

**1**

```
const SomeComponent= function(props) {
      const{
        child,
        style,
        disable,
        ...otherParam
      } = props;

      return(someOtherComponent);
    }
```

Is it different from

**2**

```
const SomeComponent= function(props) {
      const props = {
        child,
        style,
        disable,
        ...otherParam
      };

      return(someOtherComponent);
    }
```

or

**3**

```
const SomeComponent= function(props) {
      props = {
        child,
        style,
        disable,
        ...otherParam
      };

      return(someOtherComponent);
    }
```

I believe the **3**rd snippet assigns value to existing param coming as an argument in function, while **2** and **3** might be same, is this correct understanding?

If not then can someone explain to me the relevant logic of such assignment and correct technical term to these ways of assigning the values to the constants?

Comment: #2 is a `SyntaxError`, #3 is a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: 1 is using `object destructuring assignment` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Syntax) and `spread` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To settle any doubts first : **Assignment is always done from right to left**, as in 'plain olde JS' and most programming language.

However in ES6 you have a lot of new syntax to ease assignments.

Maybe what you find surprising is when some "object structure" is on the left.

There is a mix of what is called *destructuring* and some syntactic sugar when names of variables are identical to property names, it helps assign many variables at the same time, by taking them "off from" an object (or an array!),

This is not specific to `const`, it is valid for any assignment, and this syntax can also be used for function parameters.

---

### 1 : Destructuring

(assigning multiple values on the left at once from one object or one array on the right)

Examples :

```
// here a and b take the value from the source.a and source.b, respectively

const source = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
const {a, b} = source
console.log(a,b)
```

---

```
// same for arrays
// here a and b have taken the first and the second value of the source array, repectively.

const source = [1, 2, 3]
const [a, b] = source
console.log(a,b)
```

---

```
// and you can use `...` to get *all the other values*
// here a will take the first value, and b will get all the other values, which is `[2, 3]`

const source = [1, 2, 3]
const [a, ...b] = source
console.log(a,b)
```

---

### 2 and 3 : object litteral assigned

They are nearly vanilla ES5 JavaScript object assignment, with a pinch of syntactic sugar to avoid repeating the `name: name`.

`props` on the left is assigned a new object containing an object litteral created on the right.

---

The only difference between 2 and 3 is that in example 2, a new binding `const props` is created in the function scope, which actually **hide the `props` from the parameters**.

In example 3, the existing `props` as argument is *mutated* to be assigned a new value.

**I think example 2 is a programming mistake**, to be honest.

Anyway, both 2 and 3 are identitical to this "pseudo javascript" :

```
// here we susppose that there are some exiting `child` `style` `disable` variable, and an array `otherParam`
props = {
    child: child,
    style: style,
    disable: disable,
    otherParam: /* an array which is a copy of an existing "otherParam" array , with spread operator*/
  };
```

The above is shortcut syntax to reate new objects from existing variables, by keeping the same names.

Comment: Thanks liked the way you explained 2 & 3 also the details for 3 helped with how destructing with spread helps in practice

Comment: Yes, I don't have much time to wrote much about the *spread operator* to create a copy of an array, and I'm glad you already understood it !

Comment: actually I've worked with spread but destructuring is what took me by surprise :D

Comment: And I can't help thinking about [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TYv2PhG89A) when talking about "spread operator". (sorry, it's early morning by my side :) )